Time issue with 24.10 & Windows 11 Pro dual boot
I currently have a dual boot setup with Windows 11 Pro as the main OS, with Ubuntu 24.10 installed along with it. My date and time is set correctly in BIOS, and when I boot into Ubuntu, my time is correct, however, when I boot back into Windows, it is a few hours off. Toggling set time automatically resolves the issue. To permanently resolve the issue, I have come across two solutions, however they are for previous OS versions. I was wondering which is the recommended option, and if these would work with Ubtunu 24.10 with Windows 11 Pro.

Resolving within Ubuntu - running "timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock"

Resolving within Windows - this solution was confirmed for Windows 8 and 10, not for 11.
Editing the registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation.
Create new DWORD (32-bit) Value, name it RealTimeIsUniversal. Set its value to 1.
After this is done, reboot machine. After it is running, let Windows set time automatically



The hardware clock should be set to UTC and both Ubuntu and Windows should set the timezone to set the hour offset. When one OS writes to the system hardware clock it would do so in UTC and would not jump the clock by hours. I don't think registry edits are needed here
